# How can I get a single tree from an H2O Random Forest?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, h2o

I'm doing a random forest with the next code:

```
rf_md <- h2o.randomForest(training_frame = train_h,
                          nfolds = 5,
                          y = y,
                          ntrees = 500,
                          stopping_rounds = 10,
                          stopping_metric = "RMSE",
                          score_each_iteration = TRUE,
                          stopping_tolerance = 0.0001,
                          seed = 1234)
```

The output is an object with type: `h2oregressionmodel`. I want to get a single tree from the forest, so I found out that the function `getTree()` works out very well with `randomForest` objects. How can I convert my actual output to a `randomForest` object? or Can I get the same random forest with a different function which its output is a `randomForest` object?

Appreciate your  help

Answer (score 1):

H2O comes with a similar function, `h2o.getModelTree`, which can be used for both GBM and Random Forest models (see the [docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.getModelTree.html)); in your case, for selecting, say, tree #3, it should be:

```
tree <- h2o.getModelTree(model=rf_md, tree_number=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example above, rf_md *is* the H2O-3 DRF (Distributed Random Forest) object.  (Or, more specifically, a pointer to it.  The real object lives in memory in the H2O-3 java process from the h2o.init())

H2O-3 model objects are different from the native R package objects.  There is no way to convert an H2O-3 DRF model into an R randomForest model.